# How to avoid repeating actions when designing WinForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

For every form I create, I do the following:

1. Change the `RightToLeft` property to YES
2. Change the `RightToLeftLayout` property to TRUE
3. Change the font to Arial
4. Set all controls' accessibility from `Friend` to `Private`

What are my options for avoiding such repetitive actions?
Is there a "best-practice" for such a scenario?

Note: the reason I'm doing changes 1-3 is that the application's GUI is in Hebrew, and the application isn't required to support further localization or internationalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) for a form with the defaults you want. Then when adding a new form, you select your template and these would be set.

A form template would be an item template.

Comment: I would have solved this problem using inheritance. Create a base form class with all the desired properties, then have all forms in the project inherit from that one. What are the advantages of templates over this approach?

Comment: @Cody Gray - It is one way to achieve the same. Templates are good if you need to repeatedly do this in different solutions and projects, without the need to introduce an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Make a base empty form, set the attributes, then copy-and-paste into your project and rename for each new form.  Right click, copy.  Right click on project, paste.  Right click on "copy of..." and rename.